# sapui5 binding callbacks, update vs. insert vs. add

Tags: sapui5

Looking through sap.ui.base.ManagedObject has helped make the data binding in sapui5 more clear, but it's still not quite tangible yet.

A fundamental question that isn't clear to me is which callbacks get fired on a control when it's model is updated.

For example, if a control had an aggregation called items, in which situations does "updateItems" get fired? And which situations does "addItem" get fired? Also, "insertItem"?

I see that addAggregation and insertAggregation have a parameter to suppress invalidation. But I don't see that option for updateAggregation. Is there a reason for that?

Does the "bindable" metadata property alter this behavior at all?

Thanks for any insight!